# hidden html form in php with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

i'm trying to pass parameter with a html form in php, i have a php page that fill a html table:

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<form id="form1" action="search.php" method="post">';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td>id</td>';
$html .= '<td><a href="javascript:;"onclick="document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();">name</a></td>';
$html .= '<td>surname</td>';
$html .= '<td>language_id</td>';
$html .= '<td><span class="label label-success">Status_code</span></td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="mess" value=\'Hello\'>';
$html .= '</form>';
```

i can see in my html the table, when i click on the href, the search.php page it's open, but i can't see the 'Hello' value, this is the search.php:

```
<?php

$name0 = $_POST['mess'];
echo $name0;

?>
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Why do you have mess value in single quotes? place it in double and check again.

Comment: I think you should not append your html files like that, maybe remove all `.=` and just see what happens

Comment: missing $ in html @first line

Comment: there is the $, i forget to write it here, but in my code there is, i edit the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your browser not php. a good browser wont show this error. try this

```
<?php
$html = '';
$html = '<table>';
$html .= '<form id="form1" action="search.php" method="post">';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td>id</td>';
$html .= '<td><a href="javascript:;"onclick="document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();">name</a></td>';
$html .= '<td>surname</td>';
$html .= '<td>language_id</td>';
$html .= '<td><span class="label label-success">Status_code</span></td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="mess" value=\'Hello\'>';
$html .= '</form>';
$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
?>
```

and search.php

```
<?php

$name0 = $_POST['mess'];
echo $name0;

?>
```

Comment: I made some changes in the first form too. it is working here.

Comment: not work to me...and the first form it's equal to mine...what changes have you made?

Comment: I guess, you are opening the search.php directly. open the form first then click the link. i can't believe that you make that error, but you may. as you say this is not working. @piero

Comment: i can't understand what is the error, if i write the form above (or mine form) direct in the html code, i can open the search.php page and see the Hello, instead if i use php to generate that $html does not working...open page but there isn't write anything...i can't understand...

Comment: i see the html code, and i found the problem: <form id="form1" action="search.php" method="post"></form> , so open and close the form, and i can't understand why do this...

Comment: i do this: <td><form id="form1" action="search.php" method="post"><a href="javascript:;"onclick="document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();">name</a><input type="hidden" name="mess" value="Hello"></form></td> and know works...

Comment: congrats. Maybe it will be a habit to read html source now. thanks @piero

Answer (score 1):

As you said on click of href you are opening search.php and trying to get post values is not possible.

either pass value by appending the url like search.php?mess=YourValue

or 
submit the form so that you can read with $_POST

Answer (score 1):

in your form

```
<?php
$html = '';
$html .= '<form id="form1" action="search.php" method="post">';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td>id</td>';
$html .= '<td><a href="javascript:;"onclick="document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();">name</a></td>';
$html .= '<td>surname</td>';
$html .= '<td>language_id</td>';
$html .= '<td><span class="label label-success">Status_code</span></td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="mess" value=\'Hello\'>';
$html .= '</form>';
echo $html;
?>
```

in search.php

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['mess'];?>
```

Comment: That's not so much an answer to the question as it's a way to debug what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, honestly I don't know why you have SO many `.=` so, I got rid all of them

```
<?php $html = '
<form id="form1" action="search.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td><a href="javascript:;"onclick="document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();">name</a></td>
<td>surname</td>
<td>language_id</td>
<td><span class="label label-success">Status_code</span></td>
</tr>
<input type="submit" name="mess" value="Hello">
</form> ';

echo $html;
```

Comment: i use .= because i need it in my code after, it's not that the problem because the html table it's correctly filled...